# A* search for Rush Hour game?

Tags: c#, algorithm, a-star

For an assignment for school I have to make a solver for a Rush Hour game.. if you aren't familiar with Rush Hour.. check this link: http://www.puzzles.com/products/rushhour.htm

For this solver I have to use the A* search algorithm, I looked on the internet a bit, and I think I quite understood how the algorithm works.. only I don't really have an idea how to implement it in the solver.. nor how I should build up the grid for the cars.. Can someone please give me some tips/help for this? 
Not a complete solution..

Comment: Just a suggestion - as I've implemented this myself.  You might want to simplify things and try a breadth first search instead - the problem space for Rush Hour is small enough that this'll solve it in no time.

Comment: You should ask your professor for some assistance.  You cannot expect people to do your homework for you.  Besides even if we do post a solution, if you use a solution off this website, you most likely be caught for cheating.  Asking for assistance from your professor is best at this stage.

Comment: I disagree.  Asking like this is a good way to learn.

Answer (score 3):

To represent the grid of cars, I'd just use a rectangular array of cells where each cell is marked with an integer -- 0 indicates "empty", and each car has a particular number, so the different cars in the grid will manifest themselves as consecutive cells with the same number.

At this point, you should be able to write a function to return all the possible "moves" from a given grid, where a "move" is a transition from one grid state to another grid state -- you probably don't need to encode a better representation of a move than that.

To implement A*, you'll need a naive heuristic for figuring out how good a move looks, so you know which moves to try first.  I would suggest initially that any move which either moves the target car closer to the goal or makes space nearer the front of the target car might be a better candidate move.  Like Will A said in the comments, unless you're solving a 1000x1000 Rush Hour board, this probably isn't a big deal.

That's all the tricky parts I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

As mquander or Will have already pointed out, the A* algorithm might be a bit an overfit for your problem.

I just give you now some hints what other algorithm you can use to solve the problem. 
I don't want to explain how those algorithms work since you can find many good description in the internet. However, if you have a question, don't hesitate to ask me.

You can use some algorithms which belong to the kind of "uninformed search". There you have for example breadth first search, deep-first search, uniform cost search, depth-limited search or iterative deepening search. If you use breadth-first search or uniform cost search then you might have to deal with available memory space problem since those algorithms have an exponential space complexity (and you have to keep the whole search space in memory). Therefore, using a deep-first search (space complexity O(b*m)) is more memory friendly since the left part of the tree which you visit firstly can be omitted if it does not contain the solution. Depth-limited search and iterative deepening search are almost the same, whereas in the iterative deepening search you increase the search level of your tree iteratively.

If you compare time complexity (b=branching factor of the tree, m=maximum depth of the tree, l=depth level limit, d=depth of the solution):

breadth-first: b^(d+1)

uniform cost: b^?

depth-fist:b^m

depth-limited: b^l if (l>d)

iterative deepening: b^d

So as you can see iterative deepening or breadth-first search perform quite well. The problem of the depth-limited search is if your solution is located deeper than you search level, then you will not find a solution.

Then you have the so called "informed search" such as best-first search, greedy search, a*, hill climbing or simulated annealing. In short, for the best-first search, you use an evaluation function for each node as an estimate of “desirability". The goal of the greedy search is to expand the node which brings you closer to goal. Hill climbing and simulated annealing are very similar. Stuart Russell explains hill climbing as following (which I like a lot...): the hill climbing algorithm is like climbing Everest in thick fog with amnesia". It is simply a loop that continually moves in the direction of increasing value. So you just "walk" to the direction which increases your evaluation function.

I would use one of the uniformed search algorithms since they are very easy to implement (you just need to programme tree and traverse it correctly). Informed search performs usually better if you have a good evaluation function...
Hope that helps you...